# my input value is not changing when i delete some content and changing state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

career is state(object array type)

```
{career.map(toCareerAndEducation)}
```

map function

```
const toCareerAndEducation = (info: Career, key: number) => {
    return (
      <Wrapper key={key}>
        <Date>
          <DateInput figure={4} placeholder='yyyy'/>
              .
          <DateInput figure={3} placeholder='mm'/>
               ~
          <DateInput figure={4} placeholder='yyyy'/>
              .
          <DateInput figure={3} placeholder='mm' />
        </Date>
        <Content>
          <ContentInput fontSize={33} id={String(key)} placeholder='mainContent' onChange={handleOnMainContentChange} />
          <ContentInput fontSize={25} id={String(key)} placeholder='subContent' onChange={handleOnSubContentChange} />
        </Content>
        <DeleteButton id={String(key)} onClick={handleDleteButtonClicked}>
          <TrashCanIcon src={String(Trashcan)} />
        </DeleteButton>
      </Wrapper>
    )
  }
```

event handlers

```
  const handleOnMainContentChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const index: number = Number(event.currentTarget.id)
    career[index].companyName = event.target.value
  }

  const handleOnSubContentChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const index: number = Number(event.currentTarget.id)
    career[index].role = event.target.value
  }

 const handleDleteButtonClicked = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('length: ' + career.length)
    const index: number = Number(event.currentTarget.id)
    console.log('inedx: ' + index)
    var temp: Career[] = [...career]

    temp.splice(index, 1)

    console.log(temp)

    setCareer(temp)
  }
```

in this picture, i create 3 content and save it as default value, then change input value,

[create contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIE16.png)

and this is the state log

[state log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBPbU.png)

then i deleted second one

[delete second content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCncE.png)

but in browser view, it looks like delete 3rd one.

but, in state log, second element is well deleted,

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sevBl.png)

i want to view apear just same as state
how can i do that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never* modify the state object in React. This is a fundamental property of the framework and you should read the docs. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly.

In this case, career is your state I presume and you are directly modifying it in your handlers which is causing the bug `career[index].companyName = event.target.value`